# Approach for highly unbalanced panel dataset

Tags: correlation, panel-data, unbalanced-classes

I have some highly unbalanced panel data set for which I want to construct a predictive model. As the response variable consists of count data I chose to use a Negative Binomial regression model.

Due to possible multiple number of observations per individual over time I would expect the observations per individual to be possibly correlated. However, as many of the individuals only have one or two observations and some close to 40, I'm not sure whether a panel data approach would be correct here. The varying number of observations is due to the fact that an individual is observed when he or she enters some system. This can occur once or twice a year or almost every month. Below is a histogram of the number of observations per individual

[image]

Furthermore, I am not sure what role cross-sectional dependence may play due to this wide range of number of observations per individual. Also the times at which individuals are observed do not necessarily coincide as they might enter the system one or more days later.

Comment: Ever get an answer to this? I have a very similar problem.